# Rails - Add Devise user info to post

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise

I have a web app where users can sign up, via Devise, and post pictures for other people to vote on.

I'm trying to attach the users username to the photo that they upload, but I can't for the life of me figure out how.

I figured out how to get the Devise user_id into the form through a hidden field, but the username just shows up in the database as a blank field (not `NULL`, just blank).

How do I get the username from Devise to post instead of the user_id?

I have all of the appropriate `belongs_to` and `has_many` in the models.

**The form.**

```rb
<% if current_user %>
    <%= simple_form_for Picture.new, :remote => true, :html => { :class => "form-horizontal" } do |f| %>
    <%= f.input :title %>
    <%= f.input :image, :as => :image_preview, :label => false, :input_html => {:preview_version => :thumb} %>
      <div class="control-group"> 
        <div class="controls">
          <a href="#" class="btn" id="file">Choose a File</a>
        </div>
      </div>
      <%= f.input :desc, :as => :text, :input_html => { :cols => 20, :rows => 3 }, :label => 'Description' %>
      <%= f.hidden_field :user_id %>
      <%= f.hidden_field :username %>
      <div class="control-group">
        <div class="controls">
          <div class="btn-group">
            <%= f.submit "Add Picture", :class => 'btn btn-primary' %>
            <button class="btn btn-danger" id="form-cancel">Cancel</button>
        </div>
      </div>
    <% end %>
```

**pictures_controller.rb**

```
def create  
  #This line inserts the user_id into the database
  @picture = current_user.pictures.create!(params[:picture])  
  @picture.save  
    respond_to do |format|  
      format.html { redirect_to pictures_url, notice: 'Thanks for your picture!' }  
      format.js  
    end  
end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need the hidden fields. Using hidden fields also adds a security risk, a user could upload a picture and make it appear that it was uploaded by another user. To add the current user's id and username to the picture then all you need to do is modify your controller as follows:

```
@picture = Picture.new(params[:picture])
@picture.user_id = current_user.id
@picture.username = current_user.username # assuming the user model has a username field
@picture.save
```

Although a better way would be to just store the user's id with the picture and make sure the pictures model has `belongs_to :user` and the users model has `has_many :pictures`, rather than storing the username with the picture. Using this method when you want to fetch the username you can access it via `picture.user.username`

Comment: This is not answering your question so I'll leave it as a comment: You'll also want to look at into mass-assignment protection as it appears from your current code that anyone can assign the user_id and username fields for a picture also allowing anyone to upload pictures and make it appear as though someone else uploaded them. See http://guides.rubyonrails.org/security.html#mass-assignment

Comment: Thanks! Works perfectly. And thanks for the heads up about mass-assignments.